# How can I dynamically create a compiled spark view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I would like to do something like the following with spark.

```
<viewdata model="IList[[string]]" />

<for each="var file in Model">
<use import="${file}" />
</for>
```

This however, does not work because Spark is not evaluating the `${file}` before it tries the import. This makes sense and I suspected it would not work, but how else could I do something like this.

Note: The model is a list of file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use Html.RenderPartial():

```
<viewdata model="IList[[string]]" />

<for each="var file in Model">
  <% Html.RenderPartial(file); %>
</for>
```

**Edit:**

I don't believe there is much better way, but if you really don't writing RenderPartial, you can do it once. You'll have to create _useview.spark:

```
<viewdata file="string"/>
<% Html.RenderPartial(file); %>
```

and then use it like that:

```
#var views = new string[] { "View1", "View2" };
<for each="string file in views">
    <useview/>
</for>
```

Comment: That does work. We had figured that out already, but we were wondering if there was a way to do it with Spark specifically. If I don't get any better answers using Spark I'll mark you as the answer. Thanks for submitting!

Comment: Does this hack with empty useview tag really work? From what I see in spark google groups, all the views are put together at compile time. They also do not suggest anything except RenderPartial.

Comment: It works. It is the same as upper solution, but RenderPartial is moved to partial view. for each 'file' variable is visible in scope of '_useview'. Spark generated view code is the same in both solutions.